# Modify LinkedList after traverse

Tags: java, linked-list

I am using a LinkedList, I need to add an element to the LinkedList immediately after traversing it.
I mean, let's suppose I have a LinkedList of unsorted integers.

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(4);
list.add(2);
list.add(5);
```

I want to add a zero after each even number.

```
var itr = list.listIterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
   int i = itr.next();
   if (i % 2 == 0) {
      itr.add(0);
   }
}
```

After executing this, I get the LinkedList containing: [4, 0, 2, 0, 5]

**Now** suppose I want to add a zero **only** after the smallest even number.
I know I can first search the smallest even number traversing the LinkedList in O(n) and then using the .add(index, element) to add the zero after the smallest even number. The add(index, element) method runs in average O(n) since it needs to traverse some nodes of the list, I would like to avoid it and perform my operation of adding a zero after the smallest even number in a single traverse. Is that possible?

**Update**
Thanks so much guys for your answers. I'll try to write a pseudocode, I think if I was working with a custom double linked list the problem could be solved in the following way

```
Node smallest = new Node(99998);    // reference to smallest even number
While (current != Null){
   If (current.value %2 == 0 && current.value < smallest.value){
      smallest = current:
   }
   current = current.next:
}

// Link zero after smallest even number in constant time
Node zero = new Node (0);
zero.prev = smallest;
zero.next = smallest.next;
smallest.next = zero:
smallest.next.prev = zero;
```

Something like that. What do you think about it?

Comment: You'll have to write your own linked list then, that has a"Nodes" function that you can use to get what's in front and behind each node.

Comment: I am starting to believe that's the unique way :/

Comment: How would this be possible? A Linked List works in this way: Node1 -> Node2 -> Node3...

Node1 does not know that Node3 exists so the only way to get to Node3 is by traversing through Node2. And you can only know the lowest even number after you traversed through it. You might be able to make the assumption that the lowest even is 0 (or 2 if there are no 0) but that will not results in a faster Lambda notation.
The easier way for this might be to use a normal List but traversing through it has the complexity O(2n)=O(n) which is the same as your current complexity and might not be faster

Comment: You would have to insert the 0-node after the first one, remember the value and location of it, and compare it with the next nodes you iterate. When you bump into a smaller value, then *remove* the 0-node and reinsert it at its better spot. Continue like that. However, even though this represents one traversal, and is O(n), on average it will do more work per step in that iteration, and so the 2-passes solution will on average be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Though it might not be the most efficient, but you might use two iterators.

- First for list traversal
- Second for smallest numbers traversal

The issue is, when the smallest number is found, then the second iterator must catch up with the first iterator, so you end up calling `Iterator#next()` `n`-times, where `n` is difference between indices of the old and the new smallest number.

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
  int i = itr.next();
  if (i % 2 == 0 && i < smallest) {
    smallest = i;
    while (smallestItr.nextIndex() != itr.previousIndex()) {
      smallestItr.next();
    }
  }
}
System.out.println(smallestItr.next())
```

Otherwise, I would say if you need to put number into specified index in reasonable time complexity, use reasonable data structure for it.